# adding border to CircleMarkers with leaflet and R

Tags: r, maps, leaflet

I would like to add border to the CircleMarkers. I used the following code. I can't find any function to add black border to the stroke.

```
pal <- colorNumeric(palette = 'RdYlBu', domain = city_results$ratio)

m <- leaflet() %>% 
     addTiles() %>% 
     setView(lng = median(city_results$long), 
             lat = median(mean(city_results$lat)), 
             zoom = 8) %>% 
     addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB) %>% 
     addCircleMarkers(data = city_results, lng = ~long, lat = ~lat,
                     radius = ~(Socioeconomic_status_group),
                     color = ~pal(ratio),
                     stroke = TRUE, fillOpacity =  0,
                     popup = ~as.character(nameH),
                     label = ~as.character(round(corr_value,2)),
                     labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T, textOnly = TRUE))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you provide your data as well? Otherwise nobody can see your present map and give you a hand.

Answer (score 9):

If you mean that you want to use black color for stroke, the following code does the job. I used the earthquakes data from the leaflet package for this demonstration. You want to use `fillColor` to fill markers and save `color` to assign a color to strokes.

```
library(leaflet)

pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "Blues", domain = quakes$mag)

leaflet() %>% 
addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
addCircleMarkers(data = quakes,
                 radius = ~mag * 5,
                 color = "black",
                 fillColor = ~pal(mag),
                 stroke = TRUE, fillOpacity = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer,
i prefer not use fillColor , just want to add border for the circle marker,
is it possible?

Comment: @user6041789 If you just want the black strokes only, you can make the fillOpacity zero. `fillOpacity = 0` instead of 0.5. Then, you will not see any fill colors.

Comment: i have a lot of circles, therefore i would like to have an empty (without fill) with colored stroke,
the problem is that i have some colors in my pallet that are very close to the background color, like in the example above, i have some light blue colored strokes, in order to  let the user any indication that there is a stroke with light blue color i would like to give the stroke black border so the user could realize that there is a stroke at that area.

Comment: @user6041789 I think that is not possible in leaflet. You can control stroke and fill color, but not borderlines.

Comment: @user6041789 The only thing I can think now is that you want to change the map you have. If you change your background, you may not have to struggle.

Comment: @user6041789 I have no idea, unfortunately. I did what I could do for you.