# Change line width of leaflet's stroke in leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

Is it possible, to make the black line thinner?
Here's a reproducible example, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48863797/5784831):

```
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap, group = "OSM") %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, group = "Toner Lite") %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OSM", "Toner Lite")) %>% 
  leaflet::addCircleMarkers(lat = 0,
                            lng = 0,
                            color = "black",
                            fillColor = "red",
                            stroke = TRUE,
                            popup = "hello",
                            radius = 10,
                            fillOpacity = 0.7)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specifiy the stroke weight with the `weight` argument:

```
library(leaflet)

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap, group = "OSM") %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lat = 0,
                   lng = 0,
                   stroke = TRUE,
                   weight = 1)
```

[image]

```
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap, group = "OSM") %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lat = 0,
                   lng = 0,
                   stroke = TRUE,
                   weight = 100)
```

[image]